# Kotlin coroutines get results from launch

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm new to kotlin and its concept coroutine.

I have below coroutine using withTimeoutOrNull -

```
    import kotlinx.coroutines.*

    fun main() = runBlocking {

        val result = withTimeoutOrNull(1300L) {
            repeat(1) { i ->
                println("I'm with id $i sleeping for 500 ms ...")
                delay(500L)
            }
            "Done" // will get cancelled before it produces this result
        }
        println("Result is $result")
    }
```

Output -

```
    I'm sleeping 0 ...
    Result is Done
```

I have another coroutine program without timeout -

```
    import kotlinx.coroutines.*

    fun main() = runBlocking {
        val result = launch {
            repeat(1) { i ->
                println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
                delay(500L)
            }
            "Done" // will get cancelled before it produces this result
        }

        result.join()
        println("result of coroutine is ${result}")
    }
```

output -

```
    I'm sleeping 0 ...
    result of coroutine is StandaloneCoroutine{Completed}@61e717c2
```

How can I get the result of computation in kotlin coroutine when I don't use withTimeoutOrNull like my second program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`launch` does not return anything, so you have to either:

1. Use `async` and `await` (in which case, `await` does return the value)

   ```
   import kotlinx.coroutines.*

   fun main() = runBlocking {
       val asyncResult = async {
           repeat(1) { i ->
               println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
               delay(500L)
           }
           "Done" // will get cancelled before it produces this result
       }

       val result = asyncResult.await()
       println("result of coroutine is ${result}")
   }
   ```
2. Not use launch at all or move your code that is inside the launch into a suspending function and use the result of that function:

   ```
   import kotlinx.coroutines.*

   fun main() = runBlocking {
       val result = done()
       println("result of coroutine is ${result}")
   }

   suspend fun done(): String {
       repeat(1) { i ->
           println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
           delay(500L)
       }
       return "Done" // will get cancelled before it produces this result
   }
   ```

Comment: I should also note that in both these scenarios, you have to take care of the error thrown by either the code-block of the async or the suspending function, inside runBlocking (in a try catch) (since in the original code, launch would not rethrow the error and instead will give it to the general error handler. You can check [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html) for more info.